# Google Cloud MySQL managed Instance using 100 procent CPU for hours. What is using it?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

On our Google Cloud managed MySQL instance we have the following problem.

[image]
...as can be seen from the picture CPU usage has been on 100% for more than 5 hours. This is not the normal.

**Tried**
- Connected to the MySQL instance via Google Cloud Shell. To execute `show full processlist;` & `show processlist` ... nothing of interest there.
- Executed `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;`. I see no problems.
- Google Stackdriver Monitoring is not giving me any extra info I can use. Just the same CPU usage graph.

All in all I can't see the MySQL instance itself is not okay. Services having data on the MySQL instance are performing as the usually do.

---

So how would I get info on what is actually using the CPU on our MySQL managed instance?

Of course I could restart the instance and the issue would likely go away again, but I would like to drill down into what is going here.

---

Info:
- MySQL v5.7

---

Thank you very much.

---

**Update 181206**

- Executing `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`, find it here -> https://pastebin.com/M67FD5Vk
- Executing `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`, find it here -> https://pastebin.com/cvsytBMY
- The product in use is Google Cloud's, Cloud SQL solution, which is a managed MySQL instance. More info here -> https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/ (I think I stated that it the original question as well. However, now there is a link to the product documentation as well).
- The instance is `db-n1-standard-1`. More here -> https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing
- Executing `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`, find it here -> https://pastebin.com/XNPgcBms

Comment: I advice you to contact Googles helpdesk for this problem

Comment: It very much could end being what I will do. Thank you @RaymondNijland

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck ... the issue is that this is on Google Cloud. I can connect to the MySQL instance itself. Not the server running the instance. So cmds like `top` is not available to me. However, I've the info I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I'm not on Skype.

Comment: Please also post SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; so we can see your 'sleeping' processes.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added the info you request. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsBingchong Please ask your Google Cloud to help you post this  Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo  for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry I have not. I don't know when. Currently this is far down the list of tasks. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your Google Cloud  Database Flags

```
log_error=/mysql/logs/error.log  # from default of stderr will allow you to view your entries and take corrective action
max_connections=512  # from 4000 to conserve RAM and your max_used_connections was 110 in 6 days
thread_cache_size=100  # from 48 to reduce threads_created of 204 (for CPU busy reduction)
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  # from 2  you have SSD and should be using 0 per refman
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 2048 to reduce CPU busy every second
innodb_page_cleaners=4  # from 1 to expedite cleaning and reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 791
open_files_limit=10000  # from 1,048,576 will conserve RAM and be adequate
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM - you are NOT using QC
query_cache_limit=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM - you are NOT using QC
```

Research needed to explore WHY
A) 56,133 aborted_clients in 6 days
B) com_stmt_prepare is 213 greater than com_stmt_close meaning resources were not released 213 times in 6 days when finished
C) is it necessary to have innodb_log_compressed_pages ON in your flags?
This is causing part of 1GB of logging per 1/2 hour through your log files that are rotating every 14 minutes on your system.

Use of our Utility Script named findfragtables.sql will help you confirm your tables are compressed and therefore using CPU to uncompress/compress with each activity.  At innodb_compression_level=6 you are spending much CPU time with compression.
Delete, Insert, Updates at 6,538 average per second for 6 days seems to be extremely busy.

You can find my contact information on my profile, Network profile.

Comment: Thank you so much @WilsonHauck ... I will surely give your suggestions a look and get back to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Try [restarting the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance) and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @David. Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, I would really love to avoid restarting it. As the servives using the instance is working. And my purpose here is just as much to get knowhow so that I can put up meassures that will ensure that it does not happen again.
Furthermore to gaing some knowledge on how to troubleshoot such an issue on Google Cloud Cloud SQL. Thank you.